# Using a tsql trigger to keep data synced up in two tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, triggers, synchronization

I have a Products table which contains an attribute that will get updated via an ERP update by an end user.  When that happens I need the update to be replicated in another table.  I am not at all experienced with creating T-SQL triggers but I believe it will accomplish my objective.

Example:
In the `IC_Products` table:

```
Productkey = 456
StockLocation = ‘GA-07-A250’
```

In the `IC_ProductCustomFields` table (will start out the same because I will run a script to make it so):

```
Productkey = 456
CustomFieldKey = 13 
Value = ‘GA-07-A250’
```

When the `IC_Products.StockLocation` column gets updated then I want the value in new `IC_ProductCustomFields.Value` to also get updated automatically and immediately.
If a new record is created in `IC_Products` then I want a new record to also be created in `IC_ProductCustomFields`.

I would like to know how to write the trigger script as well as how to implement it.  I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Products_SyncCustomFields] ON [dbo].[IC_Products] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    -- First, we'll handle the update. If the record doesn't exist, we'll handle that second
    UPDATE IC_ProductCustomFields
    SET Value = inserted.StockLocation
    FROM IC_ProductCustomFields cf
        INNER JOIN inserted -- Yes, we want inserted. In triggers you just get inserted and deleted
            ON cf.Productkey = inserted.Productkey AND CustomFieldKey = 13;

    -- Now handle the insert where required. Note the NOT EXISTS criteria
    INSERT INTO IC_ProductCustomFields (Productkey, CustomFieldKey, Value)
    SELECT Productkey, CustomFieldKey, Value
    FROM inserted
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM IC_ProductCustomFields 
        WHERE Productkey = inserted.Productkey AND CustomFieldKey = 13
    );

GO
```

You could, I think, do separate triggers for insert and update, but this will also have the side-effect of restoring your (supposed?) invariants if the custom fields ever get out of sync; even in an update, if the custom field doesn't exist, this will insert the new record as required to bring it back into compliance with your spec.

Comment: Thank you Dominic.Well this certainly looks like it will work.  I will give it a try in a test instance.  So when I execute this it will be implemented at that time?  If so, how would I remove it if need be?  I've noticed in the past that sometimes triggers get switched off; I wasn't involved in the fix so I didn't know what caused that or what the solution was; re-execute the code?

Comment: The trigger will take effect as soon as you create it. I don't know a way to create a trigger in a disabled state, but you can do it from T-SQL with `ENABLE TRIGGER` and `DISABLE TRIGGER` or via SSMS (right click on the trigger and choose Enable/Disable). I would certainly make sure to thoroughly test your trigger in a test instance, of course, as you mention, before applying it to a live system. We use triggers with our ERP system for similar purposes, and usually it works fine, but you'll want to vet it carefully.

Comment: Why we can't use `IF (@RowCount = 0) /*DO INSERT HERE*/`? It seems that it will be more effective.